# Django: I'm stuck with the admin register when dealing with foreign keys and many to many fields inside that foreign key model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model *Workout*, *WorkoutDay* and  *Exercise*.

A workout can have multiple workoutdays. A workoutday consists of multiple exercises. Each exercise can be added to multiple workoutdays. Between the relation of workoutday and exercise, there needs to be extra fields included (like amount_required).

What I would like to have in the admin view is: An admin user can add a new workout (with some fields), can add multiple workoutdays, adding multiple exercises to 1 workoutday.

I already tried to make Workoutday an inline adminModel. That works, but I cannot have exercises included in this way.

To visualise it more:

Workout 1:

```
   Workoutday1:
               Exercise1 - amount_required: 10
               Exercise2 - amount_required: 50
   Workoutday2:
               Exercise1 - amount_required: 12
   Workoutday3:
               Exercise2 - amount_required: 20
               Exercise3 - amount_required: 20
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not support nested inline admin(define inlines on InlineModelAdmin classes), [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025) here. Take a look of this app though: [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this without using 3rd party apps:

```
@admin.register(WorkoutDay)
class WorkoutDayAdmin(admin):
    fieldsets = [
        ("Exercices", {"fields": ["exercises"], "classes": ["collapse"]}),
    ]
```

Normally it should enable you to select and create multiple `exercices` (assuming the field is called `exercices`.

Comment: Sorry after re-reading your question this will not help with the nested issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class ExercisesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Exercise

class WorkoutAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id',. .... "your fields" ]
    list_filter = ["list of filters"]
    inlines = [ExercisesInline]

 admin.site.register(Workout, WorkoutAdmin)
```